# If I use D3.js to do moderate complicated user interaction related data visulization, should I choose React or Angular2?

Tags: d3.js, reactjs, angular

All:

I got some decision pain here, as beginner, say I need to build a data visualization **Application** with D3, I kinda wondering which library should I use to handler those chart drawing( it is a little bit complicated, with a lot of user action like add/remove/moving/style/animation etcs), currently this application is implement by Angular1 and not that modularized, also when data grows, the chart drawing is lagging. That is why I am thinking of switching.

Right now, I do not have much experience about either Angular2 or React, but I hear that they are both very performanced, so in terms of code complexity and performance, could anyone give me some concrete suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: You got the downvotes because this kind of question is discouraged on SO. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks, that is fine, you do not need to give me the reason. People are different, someone will find this encouraging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We currently have a large javascript application that uses `ReactJS` and `D3` charts.

It's pretty performant although we have the lucky advantage of not having to support mobile as it's an enterprise application.

One thing I would say is be aware of Reacts `shouldComponentUpdate` method and use `ImmutableJS` for your containers. We've also implemented flux and a `WebSocket` API, but if you're new to React I'd just try and get a really simple `d3` chart like a sankey working and go from there.

When you actually get to the leaf node that's a d3 chart, you can then convert `Immutable` data types to native objects but only to pass it to `d3`.

It works completely fine, I wouldn't however manage any sort of `state` in `d3`, be careful not to fall into that trap. You want to attach events like click etc. to a d3 node, but your React components should be handling those events and not d3.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is very good news to me, but could you show me a fiddle to show how do you build a line chart with Date axis and enable user interaction such as: when user hover according line area, the data point on the line will show a tooltip bubble, and when change data set, line will transition to that data presentation with animation effect?

Answer (score 1):

I have also used d3 and react. They played together perfectly fine for me, especially since d3 is also on npm and fit nicely into the bundler required to compile jsx used by react. I don't see a downside to it. As a matter of fact, http://avocadojesus.com is built entirely in react and d3js, and uses the web audio api to stream the data into different d3 data visualizations (so dont view in safari unless you want to be bored lol).

I have used angular1 on projects and been very happy with most aspects of it. I think the only place it fell short with me was on large `ng-repeat` mappings. If your front-end is architected in consideration of your users, it's very unlikely you should run into large ng-repeat problems (But I would probably avoid for any infinite scroll situations, as the ramifications of leaving all those elements in the dom can cause major problems in angular's dom rendering cycles).

I think Angular has been a bit of a disappointment to me only in that it seems to be hanging in the balance for so long. Angular2 is completely rewritten in many ways, so learning angular1 right now might cause more growing pains down the road for you, as you would obviously want to upgrade. Learning Angular2 was frustrating last time i tried to do it, as they hadn't released any documentation and were still advising extreme caution against using it for anything non-experimental. Now they are in beta, and it seems pretty safe to learn. If you are feeling brave, or if you are just experimenting and think fondly of angular1 then angular2 is a good choice for you. The right tool for you should be one that you really love to work with, and both projects have excellent support docs and community so its safe either way IMHO

If it were up to me, I would stick with react. There is a large community built around it, and the framework is very simple. The simplicity of it is what really allows it to shine. It trains you in the proper way to collect, distribute, and update data to affect the state of all your components. If you are brave and skilled, i would recommend doing a deep dive into the flux framework as well, as it is fairly complicated, but allows you to see how well such a simple component architecture can do when informed by a sophisticated set of data stores and actions. Conceptually, it was very enlightening for me, and it informs all the code that i write now. My rails has even been getting fluxy lately haha >.<

Comment: Thanks, this is very good news to me, but could you show me a fiddle to show how do you build a line chart with Date axis and enable user interaction such as: when user hover according line area, the data point on the line will show a tooltip bubble, and when change data set, line will transition to that data presentation with animation effect?

Comment: wow sounds fun! I am unfortunately not available for such an involved demonstration at the moment, but I will revisit this post tonight and see what i can do to help you out! :)

Comment: That is fine. Thanks anyway.